# TabBar storyboard how do i connect?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

How can i create the viewcontroller for the tab bar ? I want that the bar is in that position [image]

Answer (score 1):

1- Add a containerView right with the same frame as you want for the tabBar

2- You will get a segue to an empty VC , select it and from menu Editor -> Embed in a tabBarcontroller

//

From object library drag a containerView

[image]

//

Select the segue destinaution VC and from Menu

[image]

you will get

[image]

Comment: i don't understand the 2 passage

Comment: Sh_Khan the tab bar is hidden from the main tab bar. How i put the tab bar up?

Comment: the view in my photo is an item of the another tab bar so the new tab bar is in contrast with the main tab bar

Comment: change the background ,,

Comment: you don't understand me. I want to shift the tab bar to the top of the frame. How can I do?

Comment: because if I leave the tab bar down , it is in contrast with another tab bar

Answer (score 0):

You can add a TabBarViewController as a childViewController.

1. Instantiate in YourViewControllers’ viewDidLoad the TabBarViewController.
2. Call `add(tabBarViewController)` (the extension below) inside YourViewControllers’ `viewDidLoad`.
3. Place an empty NSView inside YourViewController where you want the TabBarViewController to be. The added NSView is your tabBarAnchor.
4. Create a IBOutlet to your tabBarAnchor inside YourViewController.
5. Then inside the YourViewControllers’ `viewDidLout` you constrain the edges of your tabBarViewController to the tabBarAnchor.

Then you should see your TabBarViewController correctly placed inside YourViewController.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func add(_ child: UIViewController) {
        addChildViewController(child)
        view.addSubview(child.view)
        child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
    func remove() {
        guard parent != nil else {
            return
        }
        willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        removeFromParentViewController()
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Source: https://medium.com/@johnsundell/using-child-view-controllers-as-plugins-in-swift-458e6b277b54